# IBM Maximo 7.5 How to force a user to logout with action or automation script?

Tags: maximo

In Maximo 7.5 - Is it possible to force a user to logout using actions or automation script? The case scenario is - User follows the workflow and automaticaly gets logged out after the last action.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the presentation xml and found the answer, it takes about 3 minutes. Your mxevent is - signout. Just in case, next time try to explore all sources u have.

Comment: Thank you! But a question still how to fire that event from WF.